# Is there a way to transform both the data matrix and labels in a single pipeline before fitting a model in sklearn?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, pipeline, rfe

Suppose I have

- a data matrix `X` (numpy ndarray, all features are numeric)
- labels `y` (numpy array of string).

I want to apply `SimpleImputer(strategy='mean')` and `StandardScaler()` to `X`, and `OrdinalEncoder()` to `y`. After receiving the transformed data, I want to use `LogisticRegression()` estimator for `RFE()` to select 2 most important features from the data.
Is there a nice way to create a single `Pipeline()` to perform this task?
If not then how can this be done?

I want to use the `Pipeline()` instance like this :

```
pipe = Pipeline(<some code>)
important_matrix = pipe.fit_transform(X, y)
```

Comment: Why do you want to apply `OrdinalEncoder` to `y`?

Comment: @BenReiniger , because y contains strings, there are only two classes, so ordinal encoder simply converts the two classes into 0-1 codes.

Comment: `LogisticRegression` / `RFE` should do that internally.